# How to run port lookup command in python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using terminal command

```
while ! echo exit | nc 10.0.2.11 9445; do sleep 10; done
```

in my commandline to lookup port in my remote machine.( it is working fine). I want to do this operation inside my python script. I found subprocess and I want to know that how can I do this with subprocess ?

```
from subprocess import call
call(["while xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` does not by default use a shell to run its commands. Therefore, things like `while` are unknown commands. Instead, you could pass `shell=True` to `call` ([**security risk** with dynamic data and user input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)*) or call the shell directly (the same advice applies):

```
from subprocess import call
call("while ! echo exit | nc 10.0.2.11 9445; do sleep 10; done", shell="True")
```

or directly with the shell, this is (a) *less portable* (because it assumes a specific shell) and (b) *more secure* (because you can specify what shell is to be used as syntax is not unified over different shells, e.g. `csh` vs. `bash`, and usage on other shells may lead to undefined or unwanted behaviour):

```
from subprocess import call
call(["bash", "-c", "while ! echo exit | nc 10.0.2.11 9445; do sleep 10; done"])
```

The exact argument to the shell to execute a command (here `-c`) depends on your shell.

You may want to have a look at the [`subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html), especially for other ways of invoking processes. See e.g. `check_call` as a way of checking the return code for success, `check_output` to get the standard output of the process and `Popen` for advanced input/output interaction with the process.

Alternatively, you could use `os.system`, which implicitly launches a shell and returns the return code (`subprocess.check_call` with `shell=True` is a more flexible alternative to this)

* *This link is to the Python 2 docs instead of the Python 3 docs used otherwise because it better outlines the security problems*